# Why does rigify character deform when moving along axis

Tags: animation, rigify, axis

I have a character that has been rigged with rigify.

I have posed in various ways to run etc using pose mode. Total number of keyframes is around 400.

I would now like to move the character along the Y axis, so it appears to run whilst the running poses take place. However, when I do this, all the body parts begin to jumble about and separate.

See screengrabs - before and after grabbing and moving along a single axis.

[image: before moving]

[image: after grabbing and moving along Y axis]

Why would it do this when I'm moving the whole body? Do I need to be moving something other than the mesh?

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the mesh object that you need to move, but the armature, if you move the object away from its armature it will deform. So make the armature visible and keyframe it instead:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much man. Really appreciate it. :)